# Find a close form for obtaining the coefficients of a sequence of polynomials

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given the sequence of following polynomials of order 1 to 6, how can I generate the coefficient of the polynomial of order $n$ using the first 6 entries?

\begin{align}
1\\
x+1\\
x^2+4x+1\\
x^3+11x^2+11x+1\\
x^4+26x^3+66x^2+26x+1\\
x^5+57x^4+302x^3+302x^2+57x+1\\
x^6 + 120x^5 + 1191x^4 + 2416x^3 + 1191x^2 + 120x + 1\\
\vdots\mspace{100mu}
\end{align}

Comment: What polynomials/coefficients? The coefficients are already written for all of the ones you've shown.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Please see my edit. Thanks

Comment: The last edit hasn't improved the question at all. Again, I only see 6 polynomials. We can't answer a question unless you give us the necessary information to know what you want solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These seem to be [Eulerian polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number).  See [OEIS sequence A008292](https://oeis.org/A008292) and references there.